# how to use UITabBarController's shouldSelectViewController delegate method

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I have a tabbar-based application (tabbar controller is added in window itself) and all the navigation controller with their respective root view controllers are being set in window's xib. I have 4 tab bar items.

Suppose I click on item 1, then the root view controller for that item is being shown to me. This root view contains a table with 5 cells. If I click on a row, then a new view is pushed onto the navigation stack. Now, this pushed view has a button clicking on which will again push a new view controller. I have 4 such view controllers which are getting pushed one after the other on navigation stack.

Now, lets say I am on 3rd view in navigation stack and then, I have clicked on tab bar item 1 (the same on which I clicked earlier); then, the first root view controller is shown and my whole navigation stack is gone. I just don't want this to happen, that is, I want to remain on the 3rd view controller and also, be able to click on all tab bar items (dont want to disable any item). I know that it can be achieved through implementing tab bar controllers delegate method: shouldSelectViewController, but i dont know how??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

perform a check for the currently selected viewcontroller.
if current is the same as the tab tapped, then return no in your delegate method. Think something like this is what you mean?

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController; 
{
if ([[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:tabBarController.selectedIndex] == viewController)
    {
    return NO;
    }
else
    {
    return YES;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Hey Nik, thanx a lot yaar. This 2 lines solved my problem. Hats off to you man.... :)

Comment: No probs. sure there will be a more elegant method available.