# Switch tab bar control without playing the song from begining

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have an app with 4 tabs .

In one of it I have a list with songs. When one row is selected another view controller in the same tab is appearing.

This view :[image: this view]

I want when i select the last tab to show exactly this view , with the currently song playing.

Any ideea how can i do this , without starting the song from begining ?

Comment: Would like to see some code, but my first guess would be to not call the playing-song in viewWillAppear

Answer (score 0):

use tabbarcontroller's shouldSelect or didSelectmethod similar to this:

When you try to select the same tab again, check if music is playing, if it is playing then don't pop to root view controller

[how to use UITabBarController's shouldSelectViewController delegate method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8606449/how-to-use-uitabbarcontrollers-shouldselectviewcontroller-delegate-method)